# Substring after nth occurrence of substring in a string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to substring a string like this from oracle db:

`12/10 10:43:32:  - 170000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 175000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 180000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 185000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 190000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 195000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 200000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 200400 subs exported<br /> 12 / 10 10 :43 :32 :processing completed successfully`

to just last 3 line:

`12/10 10:43:32:  - 200000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 200400 subs exported<br /> 12 / 10 10 :43 :32 :processing completed successfully`

I have try this:
`substr(string, instr(string, '<br />', 1, 1)+2)`

But in some cases I don't know how many `<br />` there are, so I find it difficult to found begin index of last 3 line. (Data type of this column is CLOB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one option:

- regexp_count finds number of `<br />` strings within the column (so you'll have to subtract `2` from that number to get the last 3 *lines*
- the rest is simple; use `SUBSTR` which starts from the previously calculated position and return the rest of the column value

---

```
SQL> select
  2    substr(col, instr(col, '<br />', 1, regexp_count(col, '<br />') - 2) + 6) result
  3  from test;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12/10 10:43:32:  - 200000 subs exported<br />12/10 10:43:32:  - 200400 subs expo

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can also find the 3rd occurrence of `'br />'` counting from the end of the string **backwards**, by specifying a negative value (i.e -1) for the 3rd parameter of INSTR and your desired occurrence number (i.e. 3) as the 4th parameter.  e.g.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(mytext, INSTR(mytext, '<br />', -1, 3) + 6) AS answer FROM test
```

This should also give you the last 3 lines.